# Access denied to Network folder from .NET Web App with Everyone permission

Tags: asp.net, permission-denied

Trying to get a web app I am developing to move a file from one location to another.

The code I am using is:

```
var oldlog = @"\\srvr-01\logs\" + file.Name;
var newlog = @"\\srvr-01\logs\archive\" + file.Name;

File.Move(oldlog, newlog);
```

Every time I hit the line, I am getting an "Access Denied" error.

I have tried:

- Setting the identity that the Application pool runs under to a user that has confirmed Full Access to the source and destination folders
- Turning Off Anonymous Authentication on the IIS server
- Granting `Everyone Full Control` NTFS and Owner Share rights on the source and destination folders

I can't believe its THAT hard to do this, so its obvious it is something I am missing.

Comment: There are separate permission sets for a network share the file system. Make sure you looked at both.

Comment: Yup...I gave Full Control NTFS permissions, and Owner Share level permissions

Comment: Is your application deployed in IIS?

Comment: Can you do the copy manually? It isn't an excel file that someone has open?

Comment: Make sure log file is still not in use when try to move it to other location, irrespective of access move operation fails when file is in use by any active process

Comment: @CurseStacker Yes it is

Comment: @Nick Yes I can copy manually and no one else uses these files.  I tried setting the application pool to my account so I know it had the right privledges.

Comment: @Pranav No one else uses these files